# Calculate distance between n data points and k clusters in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, distance, automatic-differentiation

`X` is a matrix of data points, `n` by `d` in shape. `W` is a matrix of cluster points, `k` by `d` in shape. The smallest distance between a datapoint, `i`, and each cluster can be calculated as follows:

```
a_dist = tf.reduce_min(X[i] - W, 0);
```

How can the distance between every data point and each cluster be calculated in a tensorflow graph method? A for loop comes to mind but no such functionality exists in tensorflow as far as I understand.

Comment: are you trying to implement K nearest neighbor? Where do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient method I have found so far is the following:

```
################
# Reshape Tensors for Calculation
################
samples = X;
centroids = W;
expanded_vectors = tf.expand_dims(samples, 0)
expanded_centroids = tf.expand_dims(centroids, 1)


################
# Define objective of model
################
distances = tf.reduce_sum( tf.square(tf.sub(expanded_vectors, expanded_centroids)), 2)
min_distances = tf.reduce_min(distances, 0);
```